# How can I use Ensemble learning of two models with different features as an input?

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, tf-idf, ensemble-learning

I have a fake news detection problem and it predicts the binary labels "1"&"0" by vectorizing the 'tweet' column, I use three different models for detection but I want to use the ensemble method to increase the accuracy but they use different vectorezer.

> I have 3 KNN models the first and the second one vectorizes the 'tweet' column using TF-IDF.

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
    vector = TfidfVectorizer(max_features =5000, ngram_range=(1,3))
    X_train = vector.fit_transform(X_train['tweet']).toarray()
    X_test = vector.fit_transform(X_test['tweet']).toarray()
```

> for the third model I used fastText for sentence vectorization

```
%%time
sent_vec = []
for index, row in X_train.iterrows():
    sent_vec.append(avg_feature_vector(row['tweet']))
%%time
sent_vec1 = []
for index, row in X_test.iterrows():
    sent_vec1.append(avg_feature_vector(row['tweet']))
```

> after scaling and... my third model fits the input like this

```
scaler.fit(sent_vec)
scaled_X_train= scaler.transform(sent_vec)
scaled_X_test= scaler.transform(sent_vec1)
.
.
.
knn_model1.fit(scaled_X_train, y_train)
```

> now I want to combine the three models like this and I want the ensemble method to give me the majority just like`VotingClassifier`, but I have no idea how can I deal with the different inputs (**TF-IDF & fastText**) is there another way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a custom `MyVotingClassifier` which takes a fitted model instead of a model instance yet to be trained. In `VotingClassifier`, sklearn takes just the unfitted classifiers as input and train them and then apply voting on the predicted result. You can create something like this. The below function might not be the exact function but you can make quite similar function like below for your purpose.

```
from collections import Counter
clf1 = knn_model_1.fit(X1, y)
clf2 = knn_model_2.fit(X2, y)
clf3 = knn_model_3.fit(X3, y)

class MyVotingClassifier:
    def __init__(self, **models):
        self.models = models
    
    def predict(dict_X):
        '''
        dict_X = {'knn_model_1': X1, 'knn_model_2': X2, 'knn_model_3': X3}
        '''
        preds = []
        for model_name in dict_X:
            model = self.models[model_name]
            preds.append(model.predict(dict_X[model_name]))
        preds = list(zip(*preds))
        final_pred = list(map(lambda x: Counter(x).most_common(1)[0][0]))
        return final_pred
ensemble_model = MyVotingClassifier(knn_model_1=clf1, knn_model_2=clf2, knn_model_3=clf3)
ensemble_model.predict({'knn_model_1': X1, 'knn_model_2': X2, 'knn_model_3': X3}) # Input the pre-processed `X`s
```

Comment: thank you it is a great solution but I get an Error "invalid syntax" on this line `self.models = **models`

Comment: Sorry. That was a mistake. I have edited it now. It should work with small changes.

Comment: does X1, X2, X3 represent "X_train" for each model? now I get this error for the last line `predict() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
` d

Comment: `dict_X` represent `X_test` corresponding to each model. You should pass a dataframe or a numpy array in `X1`, `X2` and `X3`. Since I did not have the exact data you had, I couldn't test this extensively but this method should work with small tweaks.

Comment: @NargesSe The reason you get that error is because the `predict()` function definition is missing the reference parameter `self`. It should be `def predict(self, dict_X)`.

Comment: The `map()` function is also missing the iterable parameter. Here, it should be `list(map(lambda x: Counter(x).most_common(1)[0][0], preds))`.